# Can the OAuth extension be used with GSuite for outbound email?

Tags: email, g-suite

I was under the impression the relatively new OAuth extension would provide support for using GSuite for outbound email, but thus far I've only found documentation detailing it's use for processing bounces or inbound email activities.

Is this possible? If so, how do you configure the delivery mechanism once the OAuth record is authorized?

Answer (score 1):

No not yet. It's being tracked at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/mail/-/issues/59